# Python Script Execution with AWS BAtch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

I created a simple docker container to run a python script from within the container:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
CMD ["test.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

I build it, `docker build -t hello-demo .` and then run it `docker run -it hello-demo test.py` and I get my output.

But what I want to do is to be able to rerun this not on my laptop but using AWS Batch. But I am not sure how to identify the container name Batch creates. When I manually build the container I specify what I am calling it, but I am not sure how to call the correct container when running my docker run command.

Any thoughts? Or am I going about this wrong?
Thanks!
D

Answer (score 0):

First, distinguish the Docker image from the Docker container. You build the Docker image and the container is a running instance of the image (refer to the [Docker overview](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#docker-objects) for more details). When you run the Docker image locally you specify what Docker image to run and also (optionally) the name of the container.

When using AWS Batch, you create a [job definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-job-definition.html) which defines what Docker image it will use. Thus, the Docker image already has to exist in some registry, be it Docker Hub, ECR or any other registry. You can also define other container properties like a command that will be run.

To actually run the Batch job, you [submit it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/submit_job.html) to the queue using the job definition (which specifies the Docker image as stated above).